# Is there any way to improve this regular expression for website URLs?

Tags: php, regex

```
^(https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,64}\.){0,127}([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{3,64})\.\w{2,4}(\/.*)?)?$
```

I only need to match website urls (without IPs, ports, username/password, etc). Are there any critical flaws in this regex?

**Edit:** Here's a slightly improved one:

```
^(https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,64}\.){0,127}([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,64})\.\w{2,7}(\/.*)?)?$
```

I've realized that domain names can't begin or end with a dash. Is there a simple way to not match domains that begin or end with dash?

Comment: It doesn't match `http://test.co.uk/` or `http://example.museum/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part you are very restrictive and allow only the characters `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]`, where in the last part you allow anything, but newline.

==> In the first part you are missing many valid characters and in the last part you match anything till the end of the string.

Why not simplify this and match anything that starts with `http` and has no whitespace till the end?

```
^https?:\/\/\S+$
```

To avoid the starting/ending dash in the domain name use lookarounds in your second expression. I also replaced the `.*` with `\S*`

```
^(https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,64}\.){0,127}((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,64})(?<!-)\.\w{2,7}(\/\S*)?)?$
```

See it [here online on Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2vaj5)

Why have you made your complete expression Optional with the surrounding `()?`. So it will also match an empty string.